# Tkinter Button has a minus sign by default

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the tinker `Radio Button` in my app as follows !

```
# Get checkboxes for Main Coin Selector
    checkbox_btc_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="BTC", variable=main_coin, value="btc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_bcc_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="BCC", variable=main_coin, value="bcc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_dash_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="DASH", variable=main_coin, value="dash", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_doge_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="DOGE", variable=main_coin, value="doge", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_eth_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="ETH", variable=main_coin, value="eth", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_ltc_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="LTC", variable=main_coin, value="ltc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_nxt_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="NXT", variable=main_coin, value="nxt", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_str_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="STR", variable=main_coin, value="str", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_nem_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="NEM", variable=main_coin, value="xem", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_xrp_main = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="XRP", variable=main_coin, value="xrp", command=do_analyze_coin)

    # Get checkboxes for Coin Selector
    checkbox_btc = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="BTC", variable=coin, value="btc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_bcc = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="BCC", variable=coin, value="bcc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_dash = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="DASH", variable=coin, value="dash", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_doge = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="DOGE", variable=coin, value="doge", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_eth = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="ETH", variable=coin, value="eth", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_ltc = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="LTC", variable=coin, value="ltc", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_nxt = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="NXT", variable=coin, value="nxt", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_str = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="STR", variable=coin, value="str", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_nem = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="NEM", variable=coin, value="xem", command=do_analyze_coin)
    checkbox_xrp = tkinter.Radiobutton(app.window, text="XRP", variable=coin, value="xrp", command=do_analyze_coin)

    # Load Coin selector Button
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_btc_main, rown=1, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_bcc_main, rown=2, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_dash_main, rown=3, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_doge_main, rown=4, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_eth_main, rown=5, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_ltc_main, rown=6, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_nxt_main, rown=7, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_str_main, rown=8, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_nem_main, rown=9, columnn=3)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_xrp_main, rown=10, columnn=3)

    # Load Coin selector Button
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_btc, rown=1, columnn=4)
    checkbox_btc.deselect()
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_bcc, rown=2, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_dash, rown=3, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_doge, rown=4, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_eth, rown=5, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_ltc, rown=6, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_nxt, rown=7, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_str, rown=8, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_nem, rown=9, columnn=4)
    app.load_coin_selector_checkbox(checkbox_xrp, rown=10, columnn=4)
```

This is the code in another file to create and load the `Radio Button` into the app

```
def create_coin_selector_checkbox(self, checkbox_text="Text", checkbox_value="Value"):
        return tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self.window, 
            text = checkbox_text,
            variable=checkbox_value
        )

    def load_coin_selector_checkbox(self, checkbox, rown = 0, columnn = 0):
        checkbox.grid(
            row=rown,
            column=columnn, 
            sticky='W',
            ipady = 2.5
        )
```

The problem is that the `Radio Buttons` in the second column is getting displayed with a minus sign . While the `Radio Buttons` in the first column are displayed correctly . I want the  `Radio Buttons` in the second column to look like the  `Radio Buttons` in the first . Here is the snapshot of the app window !

Comment: If you're asking a debugging question then you must provide an example which is the **smallest amount of code which can reliably produce the problem**, please review [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and amend.

Comment: This is too much code. If you're asking radiobutton, we don't need to see 20 radiobuttons. Just one or two ought to be enough. See [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How can I upload an image ? I need 10 reputation points

Comment: you don't need to upload an image if you can provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbuttons by their very nature are designed to be either on or off. In your case, you're setting them to a third value, the empty string. By default, the empty string is the value of the `tristatevalue` option. Meaning, if the value is the empty string, the checkbutton is displayed in a third state. Some other toolkits call this the *indeterminate* value.

The reason for this is to support a parent that has some children selected. If they are all selected you might check the parent, if they are all unselected you might deselect the parent, but if some children are selected and some are not, you need a third visual state for the parent. Thus, tkinter supports the tristate value for this use case.

From the canonical [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm):

> If a checkbutton is selected then the indicator is normally drawn with a selected appearance, and a Tcl variable associated with the checkbutton is set to a particular value (normally 1). The indicator is drawn with a check mark inside. If the checkbutton is not selected, then the indicator is drawn with a deselected appearance, and the associated variable is set to a different value (typically 0). The indicator is drawn without a check mark inside. **In the special case where the variable (if specified) has a value that matches the tristatevalue, the indicator is drawn with a tri-state appearance and is in the tri-state mode indicating mixed or multiple values.**

You can fix this by one of the following methods:

1. explicitly set the checkbutton value to one of the valid values (either the `onvalue` or `offvalue`), or
2. setting the value to something other than the `onvalue`, `offvalue`, or the empty string, or
3. explicitly setting `tristatevalue` to something other than the `onvalue`, `offvalue`, or empty string, and then setting the value to the empty string